Defining function for domain with smooth boundary
The following is a part of exercise 3 from Chapter 1 of Steven G. Krantz' book "Geometric Analysis of the Bergmann Kernel":
Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a domain. Suppose that $\partial\Omega$ is a regularly imbedded $C^j$ manifold, $j=1,2\ldots.$ This means that, for each $P\in \partial \Omega,$ there is a neighborhood $U_P\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ and a $C^j$ function $f_P:U_P\to \mathbb{R}$ with $\nabla f_P\neq 0$ and $\{x\in U_P:f_P(x)=0\}=U_P\cap\partial \Omega.$ Prove that there is a function $\rho:\mathbb{R}^N\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying

$\nabla \rho\neq 0$ on $\partial\Omega.$
$\{x\in \mathbb{R}^N:\rho(x)<0\}=\Omega.$
$\rho$ is $C^j.$

I think I know the intended solution for this exercise but I have difficulties with some details, in short, my strategy is to take the $f_P$ and paste them together using partitions of unity.
The details
Take the cover $\{U_P\}_{P\in\partial \Omega}$ and produce a locally finite subcover $\mathcal{U}'$ of $\partial\Omega.$ Extend $\mathcal{U}'$ to a locally finite cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $\overline{\Omega}$ such that the boundary is only covered by $\mathcal{U}'$, i.e.
$$\forall P\in \partial\Omega \forall U\in \mathcal{U}:P\in U\Rightarrow \mathcal{U} \in \mathcal{U}'.$$
Now take a smooth partition of unity subordinate to the cover $\mathcal{U},$ $\{\chi_U\}_{U\in\mathcal{U}}.$ Next it should be straightforward to show that we can impose without loss of generality that $f_U^{-1}((-\infty,0))\subset \Omega$ (we can reindex the $f_P$ by the $U\in\mathcal{U}'$) but I couldn't justify this rigorously so I would appreciate some pointers here.
We can then smoothly extend $\chi_Uf_U$ to all of $\mathbb{R}^N$ for all $U\in \mathcal U$ (for $U\notin \mathcal U'$ we just set $f_U\equiv -1$) and calculate
$$\nabla (\chi_Uf_U)=\chi_U\nabla f_U+f_U\nabla \chi_U.$$
If we define $\rho:=\sum_{U\in \mathcal U}\chi_Uf_U$ we easily get conditions 2. and 3. but for 1. we have
$$\nabla \rho(P)=\sum_{U\in \mathcal U,P\in U}\chi_U(P)\nabla f_U(P) \quad P\in \partial\Omega.$$
This is nonvanishing if the sum consists of a single term but I have a hard time ruling out any cancellations that could arise from summing multiple $\nabla f_U(P).$ I tried to impose more conditions on the cover $\mathcal U'$ but my argument headed into circular territory and I think you cannot avoid having to sum over multiple $\nabla f_U(P)$ so this is another detail I would like some clarification on.
Altogether, with these problems I found it easier to use the signed distance function
$$\sigma(x):=\begin{cases}
d(x,\partial\Omega) \quad x\in \mathbb R^N\setminus \overline \Omega \\
-d(x,\partial\Omega) \quad x\in \overline \Omega
\end{cases}$$
and show that it has the required porperties in a neighborhood of the boundary using the $f_P$ and then obtain $\rho$ by smoothly extending $\sigma.$ But this approach seems too roundabout and I think the idea of using partitions of unity can work so I would be thankful if someone could show me how to fill in the details of this argument.
